# How to address this DI caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, castle-windsor

I am using `windsor castle` DI along the `Generic Repository pattern` for my `WebAPI` project.

1. User forgets the password, so he calls ForgotPassword API. This API triggers an email with some random password.
2. User login with username & random password via Login API.
3. Post to login User wishes to reset the password via calling Reset Password API.
4. User tries to login again with this new password.

But when he do so he gets the `User Credentials invalid` exception.While if he uses the old password he is able to login.

When I check in the database, password is updated correctly. But when I check DAL method that is making use of EF. The password is stil the OLD password.

But if I restart the website is IIS, then User can login with new password.

My DAL Method.

```
    public bool IsUserValid(string username, string password)
    {
        //#inspection line for me
        var user = GetUser(username);
        return user != null && password.EncryptStringAES() == user.Password;
    }

   private User GetUser(string username)
   {
      userName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) ? userName.Trim().ToLower() : string.Empty;
        return _userRepository.GetQuery()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == userName);

   }
```

If I debug at #*inspection line for me*, I see that the user object has still old password.

DI Configuration.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Classes
            .FromAssemblyNamed("CustomerApp.EF")
            .WithService.Self()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
```

I tried with `LifestylePerThread`& others but still same issue. While if I update my DAL as below.

```
public bool IsUservalid(string username, string password)
    {
        using(AppContext entities = new AppContext()
        {
            var user = (from c in entities.tblUsers
                        where c.Email == username
                        select c);
            //if I debug now, no issue 
        }
    }
```

Above patch is not Valid for me.

So what is causing this & how do I address this issue?

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're on SO now, I have to bring your attention to that fact that under their guidelines this question is too broad in terms of the possible reasons that might be causing it and/or the fact that the information provided in the question is in-sufficient.

I would suggest that since you've have identified that the user object returned still had the old password, that you focus your debugging efforts on that section of the code and maybe refine your question to the code comprising that section of your application.

Also if possible, feel free to attach/link a trimmed down version of your application that reproduces the problem which could help identify the issue.